# angularjs $http query params not working

Tags: json, angularjs, param

I have this plunker

http://plnkr.co/edit/ml1Eqvz5pZY1MgxX87s7?p=preview

i am trying to query the .json file with no success.  here is my factory

```
app.factory('myService', function($http, $q) {
   return {
 getFoo: function() {
   var deferred = $q.defer();
   $http({ url: 'foo.json', 
    method : "GET", 
    params : { 'item.id' : 0 } })

   .success(function(data) {
      deferred.resolve(data);
   }).error(function(){
      deferred.reject();
   });
   return deferred.promise;
 },

   }
 });
```

it works well but it doesn't get only the id:0.  I want not to load all data from the .json file.  I want to load only what's in id:0

any pointers?

thank you

Comment: @JBNizet In fact, what he has is just a static json file, and he is expecting http parameters to be the magic data filter ;)

Comment: @YeLiu: yes, I realized after posting my comment that this was indeed the case.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is a static JSON file. You can add every parameter you want to the request, if there is no dynamic component at server-side to interpret these parameters and serve what you want to serve, sending parameters is useless: the server receives a request for a static JSON file, and it serves the static JSON file.

Comment: I see, I didn't know that. is there any way to query a static json file?

Comment: Not using http. You'll have to download it, and filter it using JS code. In a real app, JSON is typically dynamically generated from the parameters of the query, by loading the requested data from a database and transforming it to JSON.

Comment: thank you.  my json file is apprx 40MB and I won't need all the data everytime. it would be waste of time to load all of it and filter it on the client. if i want to query the 40MB of data is my only option to put it in a database?

Comment: No, not necessarily in a database. What matters is that you need a server-side API that generates JSON dynamically. How it does it is irrelevant.